# how to extract the requested URL in rest assured?

Tags: rest-assured

I want to extract the requested URL in rest assured, I tried with `given().log().all()`
which is logging everything, I just want to extract only my Request URI.

Answer (score 3):

`given().log().uri()` would print the request uri in consloe

Comment: yeah thanks it's working, but I want to extract the URI like how we get 

getStatusCode() and getSessionId()

Answer (score 1):

"**QueryableRequestSpecification**" is an interface in Rest-Assured, which provides methods like: *getBaseUri(), getBasePath(), getBody(), getHeaders()* etc.
In order to provide reference to above interface you need to use: **SpecificationQuerier.query()** method.

Note: You might need to do some changes in your existing code. Because you need to store all the given parameters in the reference of RequestSpecification and then it's reference needs to be used to call get/post/put/delete methods.

Refer below code: (You need to provide valid baseUri and basePath)

```
RequestSpecification requestSpec= RestAssured.given().baseUri("Some Base URI").basePath("/SomeBasePath");
requestSpec.get();
QueryableRequestSpecification queryRequest = SpecificationQuerier.query(requestSpec);
String retrieveURI = queryRequest.getBaseUri();
System.out.println("Base URI is : "+retrieveURI);
String retrievePath = queryRequest.getBasePath();
System.out.println("Base PATH is : "+retrievePath);
```

Comment: You can use String class methods to merge retrieved baseUri and basePath as per your needs.

Answer (score 1):

If like me you have a basePath with pathParameters, using `queryRequest.getBasePath()` will only return the value you built the path with:

example

```
RequestSpecification requestSpec= RestAssured.given().baseUri("http://example.com").basePath("/{someid}/info");
requestSpec.get();
QueryableRequestSpecification queryRequest = SpecificationQuerier.query(requestSpec);
String retrievePath = queryRequest.getBasePath();
System.out.println("Base PATH is : "+retrievePath);
```

will return `Base PATH is : /{someid}/info`

if you need the full url with resolved basePath, use getURI() instead

```
String retrievePath = queryRequest.getURI();
System.out.println("Full PATH is : "+retrievePath);
```

will return `Full PATH is : http://example.com/1234/info`

your IDE might show the method in red like mine did (intelliJ) not sure why,
but here is the reference for the method : https://javadoc.io/doc/io.rest-assured/rest-assured/3.1.1/io/restassured/specification/QueryableRequestSpecification.html#getURI--